# Ember.js size of DS.ManyArray

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How to do it? Simple JS `.length` returns undefined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `.get('length');` instead, because `ManyArray` is a bit more special. I just use `.get('length');` all the time these days in Ember, so as to prevent problems like this, otherwise you just find yourself mixing `.get('length');` and `.length`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Where can I read about DS objects and ember-data?

Comment: Try the following guide, Nikita: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/ They're always updating it, so you have to keep a close eye on all of those pages :)

Answer (score 3):

For any Ember array, you will need to use .get('length'). Just wanted to clarify that this is not unique to the ManyArray.